# Gnuplot plots only one single value

Tags: gnuplot

gnuplot will only plot the data point 95 when plotting the following data:

```
l1 l2 l3 l4 l5
108 108 108 108 108
108 108 108 108 108
108 108 108 108 108
108 108 108 108 108
108 108 108 95 108
```

Strangely, when I remove the first two data lines, all data points will be plotted.

The code I am using is

```
file = 'xxx'
header = system('head -1 '.file);
N = words(header)
set xtics ('' 1)
set xtics ('' 1)
set for [i=1:N] xtics add (word(header, i) i)
set style data boxplot
unset key
plot for [i=1:N] file using (i):i
```

and it worked quite well for many other data series.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the `boxplot` style, your values are being plotted as lines. These lines lie at y = 108 which also happens to be the position of the upper edge of the graph unless you use `set yrange` explicitly. Therefore your graph edges are hiding your data. For instance, using `set yrange [*:109]` will allow you to see your values:

[image]

If you want automatic ways to set the yrange you can for instance use `stats` to get the max and min y values among your data and then make sure your yrange emcompasses a wider range of values.

Answer (score 0):

Try `set datafile commentschars 'l'` to skip the first line.

The `set datafile commentschars` command allows you to tell `gnuplot` what
characters are used in a data file to denote comments.  Gnuplot will ignore
rest of the line behind the specified characters if either of them is the
first non-blank character on the line.

Type `help commentschars` in the gnuplot prompt for more information.

Comment: This is not a problem in this case (see my answer) because gnuplot is already recognizing the first line (which contains non numeric characters) as a comment.